# How to export UV Masks

Tags: uv, compositing-nodes

The setup of what I'm doing I have two scenes

1. Main Scene

   1. Layer 1 is my background
   2. Layer 2 is just the billboard with UV Map
2. Billboard material

Here is a photo of my compositing nodes which should describe it better. Anyways I need the UV channel to map the second camera to the billboard. Anyways, I can only get UV when I render in Cycles.

My goal is to render out the UV as a "mask" and store that and then only rerender it in cycles when I need to. I can then do test runs in eevee to check my movements w/ materials.

How can I render out the UV to a format that can be read back in? I tried using an image but it did not work.

[image: Compositing Node Layout]

Comment: Can you show the setup you used when you tried to use an image and say more about why it didn't work?

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://imgur.com/Ptu25qr) is an example of my nodes. The bottom right nodes with the file output show how I'm getting the UV image sequence which is just saving the UV out to an image file. Then the rest of the nodes show how I'm trying to read the UV back in and reuse it to map the other render layers. As you can see the resulting image is blank for some reason.